# evaluating scope object with a element attribute in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, if-statement

I'm learning AngularJs. I following this example with a few modification and i dont get it why it does not work.

The example is as follow:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', [])
                .controller('dayCtrl', dayCtrl)
                .directive('highlight', highlight);

        function dayCtrl ($scope){
            var daysName = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'];
            $scope.data = {
                day : daysName[new Date().getDay()],
                tomorrow : daysName[(new Date().getDay() + 1)]
            };
        }

        function highlight () {
            return function (scope, element, attrs){
                if(scope.day == attrs['highlight']){
                   element.css('color', 'red');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row panel" ng-controller="dayCtrl">
            <div class="col-sm-12 page-header clearfix">
                <h4>Angular App</h4>
            </div>
            <h4 highlight="Monday">
                Today is {{ data.day || 'unknown'}}
            </h4>
            <h4>
                Tomorrow is {{ data.tomorrow || 'unknown' }}
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope you can help me with this little thing

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: `scope.day` has no value as you haven't given it one, did you mean `scope.data.day`? https://jsfiddle.net/LfLgnao4/

Comment: the h4 tag does not get red when it is monday @lipp

Comment: use this one. 
if(scope.data.day == attrs['highlight']){
                   element.css('color', 'red');
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this with `scope.data.day` in your angular [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```js
function dayCtrl($scope) {
    var daysName = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'];
    $scope.data = {
        day: daysName[new Date().getDay()],
        tomorrow: daysName[(new Date().getDay() + 1)]
    };
}

function highlight() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.data.day == attrs['highlight']) {
            element.css('color', 'red');
        }
    }
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('dayCtrl', dayCtrl)
    .directive('highlight', highlight);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="row panel" ng-controller="dayCtrl">
            <div class="col-sm-12 page-header clearfix">
                <h4>Angular App</h4>
            </div>
            <h4 highlight="Monday">
                Today is {{ data.day || 'unknown'}}
            </h4>
            <h4>
                Tomorrow is {{ data.tomorrow || 'unknown' }}
            </h4>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting around with the $scope object. Thanks